# How to copy a row depending on a value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a code that starts looking in a particular column (D) and then looks in another column (B) to see if that specific text is already being used (in B).

If it is being used, it should copy the whole row that was found in corresponding B-column and paste it above where it started looking (the one in column D).

After it finished the whole search in Column B, it should delete the initial D-row, if there was a match. It very well could be that there are multiple rows added, because there were several matches in the B-column.

My current code should be equiped to do all this as mentioned. However, it seems to be bugging on the cell command (see below). It says there is a fault with: `Rows(cellcheck).EntireRow.Copy`

```
Sub run()

Dim rng As Range
Dim check As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cellcheck As Range
Dim Delyn As Long

Set rng = Range("D2:D2500")
Set check = Range("B2:B2500")

For Each cell In rng
    'Go through every cell in column D
    RT = cell.Row

    For Each cellcheck In check
        RC = cellcheck.Row
        'Go through every cell in column B

            If Cells(RC, "B").Value = Cells(RT, "D").Value Then
                'If the text in Column B is equal to Column D then do

                Rows(cellcheck).EntireRow.Copy
                'Copy the row which we found in column B
                Rows(cell + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                'Paste it where we started in column D
                Cells(cell + 1, "B").Value = Cells(cell, "B")
                'Copy the name in column B of the initial cell into the new row
                Delyn = Delyn + 1
                'Add one to delete a row, so we know that we have to delete the row where we started this search
            End If
        Next cellcheck

    If Delyn > 0 Then
        'If we added new rows, we want to delete the reference row
        Rows(cell).Delete
        Delyn = 0
        'To avoid deletion for every row, we want to set this 0, until we find another reference in the B-column
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I hope anyone knows what seems to be the issue in this code.

So summarizing: It should basically run through 2 columns and copy all matches between column B and D and copy the corresponding B-row above the used D-row and then change the B-column name and delete the D-row.

Comment: You want to copy rows where Col B = Col D?

Comment: **1.** Insert a Column. In that put this formula (via code) = "=B2=D2" and simply copy it down **2.** Filter on that column for `True` **3.** Copy the filtered rows. No need for looping

Comment: @SiddharthRout .. Isn't the code checking every cell in one range with every cell in another ? Rather than `B2=D2`

Comment: yup@Mikku... you missed the `.. and simply copy it down...` in my comment I guess :)

Comment: #Recomment ..Use `RT = cell.row` instead of `RT = Rows(cell)`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout .. Hehe.. I didn't miss that. But that's not gonna check B2 with D3 and so on. 

Comment: @Mikku: Maybe I misundertood then... `starts looking in a particular column (D) and then looks in another column (B) to see if that specific text is already being used (in B).` I assumed that the user wanted to look in the same row..

Comment: Yeah .. It's confusing.. What I understood is that user wants to check `D2` in Entire Column `B`. @SiddharthRout

Comment: @Mikku: Let OP clarify it. Like I said, I could have misunderstood it

Comment: Wow! Thanks for helping me out! Indeed @Mikku and SiddharthRout, I want to check D2 in entire column B, then D3 in entire column B, and so on.

Comment: @D.Nijland . Did you try what i suggested you to change ?

Comment: @Mikku I think your recommended ```RT = cell.row``` already works out. Apparently I need to use something similar on this part: ```Rows(cellcheck).EntireRow.Copy```, since it starts bugging on this part.

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes, (as answer to You want to copy rows where Col B = Col D?)

Comment: RT is not defined so it's a variant. The statement RT = Rows(cell) is either attempting to assign RT as an object variable to point at the row object, (in which case it's missing the SET statement) or it's storing the contents of the row as an variant array. But your code is attempting to use it as a long - presumably you actually wanted the row number of cell. which would be given by the ROW function and not the ROWS object

Comment: @HarassedDad Thanks. I changed a bit of my code, also trying to explain it in more detail. Please see my edditted question. It now bugs on the part ```Rows(cellcheck).EntireRow.Copy```.

Comment: Rows returns a row object - so it doesn't need entirerow. You use the entirerow method with a range object to return a row. So either cellcheck.entirerow.copy  which copies the row that holds the cell cellcheck, or Rows(cellcheck).copy which copies the row whose rownumber is equal to the value held in cellcheck.

Comment: @HarassedDad Thanks a lot! This solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me out.

If anyone is interested in a similar coding, the final solution became the following:

```
Sub Run()

Dim rng As Range
Dim check As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cellcheck As Range
Dim Delyn As Long

Set rng = Range("D2:D2500")
Set check = Range("B2:B2500")

For Each cell In rng
    'Go through every cell in column D
    RT = cell.Row

    For Each cellcheck In check
        RC = cellcheck.Row
        'Go through every cell in column B

            If Cells(RC, "B").Value = Cells(RT, "D").Value Then
                'If the text in Column B is equal to Column D then do

                cellcheck.EntireRow.Copy
                'Copy the row which we found in column B
                Rows(RT + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                'Paste it where we started in column D
                Cells(RT + 1, "B").Value = Cells(RT, "B")
                'Copy the name in column B of the initial cell into the new row
                Delyn = Delyn + 1
                'Add one to delete a row, so we know that we have to delete the row where we started this search
            End If
        Next cellcheck

    If Delyn > 0 Then
        'If we added new rows, we want to delete the reference row
        Rows(RT).Delete
        Delyn = 0
        'To avoid deletion for every row, we want to set this 0, until we find another reference in the B-column
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

The issue was with me calling rows and then selecting the whole row (which was already selected). Another minor issue was calling the cell value (with the command cell), instead of asking the row number (with RT or RC).

Comment: Option Explicit at the top of the module page, and then Dim RT as long and Dim RC as long would have given you more informative error messages and are good practices to get into. (Also RC is not a good variable name as it has a specific meaning if using R1C1 notation and could lead to confusion)